# How do I import Google's OAuth client into IntelliJ via Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, google-oauth

This is my first time working with Maven and trying to include a dependency on a Java project.

I've tried following instructions online but can't seem to get a desirable result and am hoping for an explanation suitable to a 5-year-old.

[Following the setup instructions](https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Setup-Instructions), I add the following into my pom.xml:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then, I [download the latest assembly zip file from Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.oauth-client%20AND%20a:google-oauth-client-assembly&core=gav). But what am I supposed to do from here? What am I supposed to do with the contents of the zip file? I don't know what steps to take from here to be able to start working with the library, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look here, it has got detailed explanation:https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth-2.0

Comment: @eugen in what way is that supposed to be helpful to me?

Comment: ok, I guess I misunderstood you. First of all, usually Idea itself does the importing and puts into default .m2 directory, and you do not need to download anything. What made you download it yourself?

Comment: @eugen I am not the sharpest tool in the shed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dependenciesManagement` tag allows to consolidate and centralize the version of the underlying dependencies defined inside the declared one.
The project specific dependency needs to be declared in separate `dependencies` tag, outside of `dependencyManagement`.

The step of downloading the dependency archive is only for case when you need to add the required dependencies/artifacts to the program classpath manually. No need to do it when you want for your dependencies to be managed by build tool (eg Maven or Gradle).

I've done some little research and it appears that the `com.google.cloud:libraries-bom` doesn't manage the `google-oauth-client` artifact. Check out the managed dependencies section of the [libraries-bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/libraries-bom/2.2.0) which you currently import.

The latest version of `google-oauth-client` is `1.30.5` and it is managed by the different bom dependency (not managed by `libraries-bom)`.
I've found that the latest version of `google-oauth-client` is managed by its own bom dependency. So you could import it to your maven project by adding something similar to:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- this has the different libraries than the above one -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't know the origination of that issue, but the most of all is that the github wiki page you've read wasn't updated with info covering the changes in those bom managed dependencies.